# Yii2 does not create nice url - parameter

Tags: url, yii2, clean-urls, yii-url-manager

I use the URL manager in Yii2 to create nice urls, which works, as long as there are no parameters on the url.

I set up the following config:

```
urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
```

Using 
`Url::to(array('crtl/action', 'paramx' => 'computer:net', 'paramy' => 'abc'))` results in the following url:

http://localhost/crtl/action?paramx=computer:net&paramy=abc

But what I need is the following:

http://localhost/crtl/action/paramx/computer:net/paramy/abc

How can I prettify the url paramters to?

Answer (score 0):

In case we declare pretty url, if we need result followed by '/' then we also need to define url rules for routing

```
    'urlManager' => [
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'rules' => [
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>/<ids:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                ],
            ],
```

So we can call this routing as :

```
     <a href="<?php  echo \yii\helpers\Url::base(true)."/site/testing/5/8"?>">
     <a href="<?php echo \yii\helpers\Url::to(['site/testing','paramx'=>'x1','paramy'=>'y1'])?>">
```

In first case we had created the url as we want.
In second case we had used url:to for routing as we can see we had provided paramX and param y in parameter.

For both of this,the result will be,

```
      public function actionTesting() {
        print_r(Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams());
        die();
  
    }//will get the query params that we had sent

    Output will be:Array ( [paramx] => x1 [paramy] => y1 ) ;
```

As the case you are asking is not the url routing pattern for yii2,this is the preferred way for yii2

Comment: shouldn't `Url::to` create an "nice" URL, like `.../paramx/x1/paramy/y1`? Using your rule has no effect, of the output of `Url::to`. It still generates the `&parmx=x1&paramy=y1` version.

Answer (score 0):

If your argument is number then rule of URL manager will be:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

If your argument is text then rule of URL manager will be:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<name:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

Comment: my arguments are sometimes numbers and sometimes text. so I have to add both?

Comment: Yes. You have to add both.